# Express/mongoose application with common database for login to mange access to other databases

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an application in nodejs (express) with a permanent connection to a database in mongodb with mongoose. In this database there are the access data of all users with client ID, as well as other common data.

```
//server.js
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://user:pass@host/DB_Common');
```

When a user singin, I want to open a connection to the corresponding database (DB_Client001) where he will be able to see data, information... Each client will have his own database. When user logout close the connection.

```
//users.server.js

//Connection for user0001 (idClient: 001), user002 (idClient: 001), user003 (idClient: 001)...
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://user:pass@host/DB_Client001');


//Connection for user010 (idClient: 002), user011 (idClient: 002), user012 (idClient: 002)...
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://user:pass@host/DB_Client002');
```

Mongoose doesn't allow two connections at the same time and the access token for the access I don't know how to implement it in this architecture.

Comment: create one file for each connection and exports connection , when you want to use import both of them

Comment: Are you really going to create one full independent database for _each_ user? It would also mean duplicating all your models, once per database. Sounds _very_ heavy to me. If each user needed a completely different database, with completely different schemas, business needs and logic, maybe it would make sense. But in the same application, why would you want to do that? Don't give your users database-level credentials, give them application-level credentials, with application-level permissions. You are the database admin, not them.

Comment: my advice - go back to the drawing board w/ this one. you should not be spinning up connections for each user.

Comment: @mohammadNaimi you can use the createConnection method instead

Comment: @LostJon yeah ideally yes, but if he has a different DB then I guess he needs to set up a connection to a different database and have a pool created for each

Answer (score 0):

mongoose has a [`createConnection`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connections) method

try this

```
const { createConnection } = require('mongoose');

//Add all these async methods in a function that accepts URL and returns the connection

const db_common = await createConnection('mongodb+srv://user:pass@host/DB_Common')

const db_user0001 = await createConnection('mongodb+srv://user:pass@host/DB_User0001');

const db_user0002 = await createConnection('mongodb+srv://user:pass@host/DB_User0002');
```

and to check the number of connections you have you can use `mongoose.connections.length;`

This code snippet solves your problem of having multiple DB connections. But, ideally, you **shouldn't** have one DB and a corresponding connection for every user. You should change the way your application works